# Aggregate/Lookup Function between 2 collections to obtain Sku price for all the listed bundle skus

Tags: mongodb

Collection:1 - ProductCatalog:

```
{
    "productId" : "prod0001",
    "skus" : [
        {
            "skuType" : "Standard",
            "skuId" : "s00001",
            "bundleSkus": [
                {
                    "bundleSkuId":"bs1001",
                    "displayName":"Service Charge 1"
                },
                {
                    "bundleSkuId":"bs1002",
                    "displayName":"Service Charge 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "skuType" : "Enhanced",
            "skuId" : "s00002",
            "tncUrl" : "./../../../assets/html/prod0001tnc.html",
            "basicPrice" : "15"
        },
        {
            "skuType" : "Premium",
            "skuId" : "s00003",
            "bundleSkus": [
                {
                    "bundleSkuId":"bs2001",
                    "displayName":"Service Charge 1"
                },
                {
                    "bundleSkuId":"bs2002",
                    "displayName":"Service Charge 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Collection:2 - PriceList

```
{
    "bundleSkuId" : "bs1001",
    "price" : [
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "minQty" : 1,
            "maxQty" : 99999
        }
    ]       
},
{
    "bundleSkuId" : "bs1002",
    "price" : [
        {
            "amount" : 10,
            "minQty" : 1,
            "maxQty" : 99999
        }
    ]
},
{
    "bundleSkuId" : "bs2001",
    "price" : [
        {
            "amount" : 15,
            "minQty" : 1,
            "maxQty" : 99999
        }
    ]
},
{
    "bundleSkuId" : "bs2002",
    "price" : [
        {
            "amount" : 20,
            "minQty" : 1,
            "maxQty" : 1000
        },
        {
            "amount" : 19,
            "minQty" : 1001,
            "maxQty" : 99999
        }
    ]
}
```

I am new to mongo db and i have the below requirement.
Expected Result:
Need a MongoDB aggregate/lookup(which ever the possibility) function which will fetch prices of all bundleskus from PriceList Collection - based on bundleSkuId from both the tables.

I am struck with this requirement, some ones help is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your input.                                                                         I tried as you suggested but giving me empty array for the newly added property. This is working fine for simple JSON but in my case - dcm code is under an array bundlesku which is under one more array skus hence i am getting array size as 0 as per my understanding. Any inputs/suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to destructure your skus array in ProductCatalog.

```
db.ProductCatalog.aggregate([{$unwind: '$skus'}, {$unwind: '$skus.bundleSkus'}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ee87f6bea70e6b45fde632"), "productId" : "prod0001", "skus" : { "skuType" : "Standard", "skuId" : "s00001", "bundleSkus" : { "bundleSkuId" : "bs1001", "displayName" : "Service Charge 1" } } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ee87f6bea70e6b45fde632"), "productId" : "prod0001", "skus" : { "skuType" : "Standard", "skuId" : "s00001", "bundleSkus" : { "bundleSkuId" : "bs1002", "displayName" : "Service Charge 2" } } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ee87f6bea70e6b45fde632"), "productId" : "prod0001", "skus" : { "skuType" : "Premium", "skuId" : "s00003", "bundleSkus" : { "bundleSkuId" : "bs2001", "displayName" : "Service Charge 1" } } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ee87f6bea70e6b45fde632"), "productId" : "prod0001", "skus" : { "skuType" : "Premium", "skuId" : "s00003", "bundleSkus" : { "bundleSkuId" : "bs2002", "displayName" : "Service Charge 2" } } }
```

Then use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join with PriceList

```
db.ProductCatalog.aggregate([{$unwind: '$skus'}, {$unwind: '$skus.bundleSkus'}, {$lookup: {from: 'PriceList', as: 'price', localField: "skus.bundleSkus.bundleSkuId", foreignField: 'bundleSkuId'}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ee87f6bea70e6b45fde632"), "productId" : "prod0001", "skus" : { "skuType" : "Standard", "skuId" : "s00001", "bundleSkus" : { "bundleSkuId" : "bs1001", "displayName" : "Service Charge 1" } }, "price" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("58ee8815bea70e6b45fde633"), "bundleSkuId" : "bs1001", "price" : [ { "amount" : 10, "minQty" : 1, "maxQty" : 99999 } ] } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ee87f6bea70e6b45fde632"), "productId" : "prod0001", "skus" : { "skuType" : "Standard", "skuId" : "s00001", "bundleSkus" : { "bundleSkuId" : "bs1002", "displayName" : "Service Charge 2" } }, "price" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("58ee8815bea70e6b45fde634"), "bundleSkuId" : "bs1002", "price" : [ { "amount" : 10, "minQty" : 1, "maxQty" : 99999 } ] } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ee87f6bea70e6b45fde632"), "productId" : "prod0001", "skus" : { "skuType" : "Premium", "skuId" : "s00003", "bundleSkus" : { "bundleSkuId" : "bs2001", "displayName" : "Service Charge 1" } }, "price" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("58ee8815bea70e6b45fde635"), "bundleSkuId" : "bs2001", "price" : [ { "amount" : 15, "minQty" : 1, "maxQty" : 99999 } ] } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ee87f6bea70e6b45fde632"), "productId" : "prod0001", "skus" : { "skuType" : "Premium", "skuId" : "s00003", "bundleSkus" : { "bundleSkuId" : "bs2002", "displayName" : "Service Charge 2" } }, "price" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("58ee8815bea70e6b45fde636"), "bundleSkuId" : "bs2002", "price" : [ { "amount" : 20, "minQty" : 1, "maxQty" : 1000 }, { "amount" : 19, "minQty" : 1001, "maxQty" : 99999 } ] } ] }
```

You can clean up with a final [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Comment: Thank you Julien. Your solution helped me. Just a small query here - I am able to see the records in DB but not able to open all in the above.  Only one record i am able to open - if i click on second record it is default going to first record. Is it the actual behavior? or do we need to modify the query to edit all the records?

Comment: It seems to be a GUI problem. Maybe it is using the _id of your doc which is not set in your sample